# How should i get the count of products in wishlist?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer, session, wishlist

```
<li class="trigger-item">
      <?php $moduleName = 'wishlist';
      $cartCount = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getSummaryQty();?>
        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
              <a class="trigger-link-wish-list" href="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>wishlist/">
            <span class="trigger-icon icon-heart"></span>
    <?php if ($cartCount > 0): ?>
        <span class="cart-counter">
            <?php echo $cartCount; ?>
        </span>
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="cart-counter cart-counter--zero">0</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
  <?php endif;?>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wishlist item count is also stored in customer session.

```
$count = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getWishlistItemCount();
```

For not logged in customers it's `0`, so it's same as ...

```
 $count = 0;
 if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
     $count = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getWishlistItemCount();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<?php 
    $wishListCount = 0;
    if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer, true);
        $wishListCount = $wishlist->getItemsCount();
    }
?>
```

Now `$wishListCount` holds what you want.